# Remove recursively from a BST

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am finished with the case when the node that i want to remove is the root node or the leaf node, but i need to be able to remove also when it has siblings or children, which i am finding very hard.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key=None, data=None):
        self.key = key
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def remove(self, key):
        self.root = self._remove(key, self.root)

    def insert(self, key, data):
        self.root = self._insert(self.root, key, data)

    def _insert(self, root, key, data):
        if root == None:
            self.size += 1
            return Node(key, data)
        if root.key == key:
            return root
        elif root.key > key:
            root.left = self._insert(root.left, key, data)
        else:
            root.right = self._insert(root.right, key, data)
        return root

    def _remove(self, key, node):
        if node == None:
            return None
        if key == node.key:
            if node.left != None and node.right == None:  # if trying to remove root and right side is empty
                return node.left
            elif node.left == None and node.right != None:  # if trying to remove root and left side is empty
                return node.right
            elif node.left == None and node.right == None:  # if trying to remove leaf
                return node
            # two more cases to check when it has siblings

        # iterates recursively in the bst
        elif key <= node.key:
            node.left = self._remove(key, node.left)
        else:
            node.right = self._remove(key, node.right)

        return node
```

I posted the whole code so if anyone wants to test in their machine is welcome to do so, or someone can use it for educational purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future try to perform some debugging and provide some sample output and expected output.

Consider below

```
def _remove(self, key, node):
        if node == None:
            return None
        if key == node.key:
            if node.left and not node.right:  # only left
                return node.left
            elif node.right and not node.left: # only right
                return node.right
            elif not node.right and not node.left: # neither
                return None
            else : # both
                inorder_successor = node.right
                while inorder_successor.left:
                    inorder_successor = inorder_successor.left
                # remember to replace inorder_successor with it's right child
                ...
                ...
                return inorder_successor

        # iterates recursively in the bst
        elif key <= node.key:
            node.left = self._remove(key, node.left)
        else:
            node.right = self._remove(key, node.right)

        return node
```

A few observations about what changed

1. You check for `None` using, `is != None` which is a very non Pythonic way to it. Just check for `is` and `is not` instead
2. The right way to replace a node in a BST that has both children is with the inorder successor (left most descendant of the right child of the deleted node)

Comment: Thanks for your observations and your help, i just finished my self when it had both children, and tbh i did not post input and output because i assumed that those who understand this would not need any input, but yes, it is always good to have the input and expected output.